# ObjectionJS - Insert one to many and update parent

Tags: typescript, knex.js, objection.js

Hello I'm a beginner with Objection js / Knex. I have an entity `Item` which relates to another entity `Bag` I want to insert an `Item` into a `Bag` and also update the weight of the bag according to the weight of the `Item`.

`Item` class:

```
 
  id!: Id;
  weight!: number;
  bagId?: Id;
  bag!: Bag;

  static tableName = 'items';

  static get relationMappings(): RelationMappings {
    return {
      bag: {
        relation: Base.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: 'Bag',
        join: {
          from: 'items.bagId',
          to: 'bags.id',
        },
      },
    };
  }
```

`Bag` class:

```
id!: Id;
  totalWight!: number;
  items?: Item[] | undefined;

  static tableName = 'bags';

  static get relationMappings(): RelationMappings {
    return {
      cuboids: {
        relation: Base.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: 'Item',
        join: {
          from: 'bags.id',
          to: 'items.bagId',
        },
      },
    };
  }
```

I've already used `upsertGraph` and trie using `patchAndFetchById` but all of these seem to hang when I try to update the parent (Bag) and also insert the Item value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Instance Methods](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/instance-methods.html) of objection. Like [$beforeInsert()](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/instance-methods.html#beforeinsert) or [$afterInsert()](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/instance-methods.html#afterinsert)

Here an example of this with `$afterInsert()`:

```
async $afterInsert(queryContext: QueryContext): Promise<void> {
    await super.$afterInsert(queryContext);

    await Bag.query()
      .update({
        totalWight: totalWight + this.weight,
      })
      .where('id', this.bagId);

}
```

Keep in mind that this `$afterInsert()` should be added in Item class and I'm assuming that Item class extends `Model` class from `objection`